# Need help making chat in java

Tags: java, string, compare

Okay, so I have been working on a chat program. Its a WIP doesn't have networking yet. I need help checking if my "input" variable is empty. I tried checking if the length was equal to 0, but it still lets me enter a blank message. I need to make it so I can't enter blank data, and it hasn't been wanting to work.

```
if(input.getText().length() == 0) {
    chat.append(username + ": " + input.getText() + "\n");
    input.setText("");
}
```

Comment: Please don't post a link, post your actual code here.

Comment: Jakebobjo, we like questions to be self-contained. Please post a short, self-contained, correct, compilable example that illustrates the problem. See http://sscce.org/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be simple enough.

```
if (!input.getText().trim().equals(""))
{
     // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks, why does it need to be trimmed though? It was set to "" without any spaces :o - Excuse me for questions I havent used java in ages -_-

Comment: It needs to be trimmed just in case you only entered a space into the field, setting the value of input to `" "` and not `""`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a function called .isEmpty

```
if(!input.getText().trim().isEmpty()){
  //send a text
}
```